# run cmd command from project in Eclipse

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, process, cmd

I have a program, which run by cmd command.

I want to call it from my project in the Eclipse (Java).

How can I do that?

Comment: To clarify: the OP seems to want to span a new windows (cmd) shell extrenal to eclipse from within Eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Java 5 or newer:**

have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

**for older versions:**

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
By "External Tools"\"External Tools Configuration" ;)
```

Or try

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)
```

Comment: Yes, but as I understood it, it run cmd in the eclipse. I want to run the command after I reach to spcific code in my project.

Comment: @AdamSh you mean you want to run the command outside of Eclipse, but triggered by Eclipse?

Comment: Mkay... then ignore my proposal.

Comment: @AdamSh I don't have access to a windows machine, but I guess there must be a cmd flag that spawns a new shell. Try the docs here: http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html